# Readiness probe failed & connection refused inside kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I have prepared some basic example of Keycloak inside k8s https://github.com/PavelDemyanenko/kubernetes-keycloak/tree/master/kubernetes, where I have a problem that when I deploy Keycloak Helm Chart in the end of deployment I have such an error:

```
  Normal   Created         3m56s                   kubelet, oauth2-proxy-control-plane  Created container keycloak
  Normal   Started         3m56s                   kubelet, oauth2-proxy-control-plane  Started container keycloak
  Warning  Unhealthy       48s (x16 over 3m18s)    kubelet, oauth2-proxy-control-plane  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.0.9:8080/auth/realms/master: dial tcp 10.244.0.9:8080: connect: connection refused

$ kubectl get pod -o wide

NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE                         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
oauth2-proxy-example-0              0/1     Running   3          8h    10.244.0.9    oauth2-proxy-control-plane   <none>           <none>
oauth2-proxy-example-postgresql-0   1/1     Running   1          8h    10.244.0.10   oauth2-proxy-control-plane   <none>           <none>
```

What is wrong with config and why it can't check readiness probe?

**UPDATE**

```
  readinessProbe: |
    httpGet:
      path: /auth/realms/master
      port: 9080
```

And now I get:

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  83s (x2 over 93s)    kubelet, oauth2-proxy-control-plane  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.0.18:9080/auth/realms/master: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Answer (score 4):

So basicly I figured out that timeout setting helped

```
 readinessProbe: |
    httpGet:
      path: /auth/realms/master
      port: 9080
    initialDelaySeconds: 30
    timeoutSeconds: 30
```

Comment: And there should be port forwarding kubectl port-forward svc/ingress-nginx-controller 8080:80 -n ingress-nginx